# Elementary Probability Problem with Inclusion/Exclusion Principle

Tags: probability, intuition, inclusion-exclusion

I came across the following problem, and my answer is so close to being correct I wondered where I went wrong:

**Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be three events. Show that exactly two of these events will occur with probability**
$$P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap C) + P(B\cap C) − 3P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

I solved it the following way by using the Inclusion/Exclusion Principle:

$$P\big[(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C\big)]=P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap C) + P(B\cap C) − 2P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

I am so close, yet so far, and I can't figure out why, am I not allowed to apply the inclusion/exclusion principle? Did I miscalculate? Or am I not calculating what is asked of me? If so what am I calculating?

ANY help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You are computing the probability that $\textit {at least}$ two of the events occur.  You were asked to compute the probability that $\textit {exactly}$ two of the events occurred.

Comment: So, when I compute $P(X\cup Y)$ I am computing the probability that at least one event occurs, and when I compute $P(X\cup Y \cup Z)$ I am computing the probability that at least two events occur etc? Furthermore, does it make sense then to fix the way above by subtracting $P(A\cap B \cap C)$ from both sides, given that out of 3 events, exactly two occuring would means at least 2 occuring minus all of them occuring? Is that rigorous? @lulu

Comment: Well, $P(X\cup Y\cup Z)$ is the probability that at least $\textit {one}$ of the three events $X,Y,Z$ occurs.

Comment: In the given case, life is quite simple because the events "$A,B$ occur but $C$ does not", "$A,C$ occur but $B$ does not", and "$B,C$ occur but $A$ does not" are mutually exclusive.  Thus all you have to do is to add the three probabilities together, with no correction for double counting.

Comment: The solution manual did mention that, I was trying to see if there is a way to salvage my way of thinking, probability has me extremely ungrounded, and if I can't complete (rather than change) my thinking it is going to get worse :P So, one more try, can I say then $P(X\cup Y \cup Z)-P(X\cap Y\cap Z)$ is the probability of exactly two events happening? If so, can we generalize? @lulu

Comment: Still, no.  Again, your first term is the probability that at least one happens, the second term is the probability that all three happen, so the difference would include the cases where exactly one of the events happens and where exactly two of the events happen.

Comment: So the equality of my corrected answer and the real answer only holds because of the nature of the events $X=A\cap B,$ $Y=A\cap C,$ $Z=B\cap C$? @lulu thanks for taking all this time :)

Comment: I suppose. Given those events, if two of them occur then so do all three. Still seems like a terribly convoluted way to approach something simple.

Comment: I realize that, but thank you for your time :) @lulu